# How to adjust material top tabs width individually in react native

Tags: react-native, styles, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-top-tabs

[image: WhatsApp UI]

My goal is to copy WhatsApp UI. However, I am having trouble making the camera icon smaller while keeping the others flexed in the row direction. Below is code

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: colors.text,
      height: 4,
    },
    tabBarStyle: {
      backgroundColor: colors.foreground,
    },
    tabBarContentContainerStyle: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      // alignItems: 'center',
    },
    tabBarLabelStyle: {
      fontWeight: '600',
    },
    tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.text,
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: colors.secondaryText,
  }}
  initialRouteName="chats">
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Camera"
    component={Camera}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <AntDesign name="camera" size={24} color={color} />
      ),
      tabBarLabel: () => null,
      tabBarItemStyle: { width: 50 },
      tabBarIconStyle: { width: 75 },
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Chats"
    component={Chats}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Status"
    component={Status}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Calls"
    component={Calls}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

After messing around with the width of tabBarItemStyle, I noticed that on click, it changes other tabs widths as well. In the documentation for [tabBarItemStyle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#tabbaritemstyle), it says it changes the individual styling, but it is not what I am experiencing. I get the following when I click the camera icon:

### [image: my whatsapp ui]

and when I click other tabs this:

### [image: this]

I can't change the style of the tab individually, I tried lots of different variations. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why should not try custom tab bar using tabBar prop?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#tabbar

Comment: I didn't think about that. If I can't find a solution to this, I will use that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue. It seems that `tabBarItemStyle` is shared across all tab items. That's probably due to the limitation of the default tab bar component.

Perhaps in the documentation, `Style object for the individual tab items` can be interpreted as `for each tab item`

The best way I can think of is to keep the item style the same, set the `tabBarLabelStyle` individually.

```js
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Camera"
    component={Camera}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <AntDesign name="camera" size={24} color={color} />
      ),
      tabBarLabel: () => null,
      // use margin to move the icon
      tabBarIconStyle: { marginRight: '60%', width: 50 },
      tabBarIndicatorStyle: { width: 50 }
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Chats"
    component={Chats}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Status"
    component={Status}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Calls"
    component={Calls}
  />
```

[image: Result when camera is active]

Caveat:

- No smooth animation of the indicator when moving from camera to other tab

Otherwise creating a custom tab bar can give the best result, as mentioned in the comment.